# Overriding variable with group by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to override `documents` but it doesnt change at all

```
@document_days = @downloads.group_by {|t| t.created_at.strftime("%D")}
    @document_days.each do |day, documents|
              documents = documents.group_by {|t| t.id}
            end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

documents is a local variable. It doesn't change the original hash. If you want to change the hash value, do this

```
    @document_days.each do |day, documents|
      @document_days[day] = documents.group_by {|t| t.id}
    end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Now I get this error =  "can't convert String into Integer". Some advise?. See the edit, I put some other code